# How to draw using fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I just begin to use fabric.js and I want to draw something, but where should I put this code?

This is tutorial code from http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1/

```
// create a wrapper around native canvas element (with id="c")
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// create a rectangle object
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 20,
  height: 20
});

// "add" rectangle onto canvas
canvas.add(rect);
```

I tried to put in `<html>-<body>-<script>`
but I can't see any rectangle when I open in browser.
What should I do???

Comment: Did you put it in a <script> tag?

Comment: Did you include the fabric.js itself? Are there any errors on console?

Comment: Umm.. Could you check my code??.. It's very short

Comment: I put 
<script src="fabric.js"></script>

Comment: And is fabric.js loading from the same folder as the html file, as <script src="fabric.js"></script> indicates?

Comment: It should work, check my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pajusmar/mgz27e6d/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fabric</title>
    <script src="fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    <script>
        // create a wrapper around native canvas element (with id="c")
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

        // create a rectangle object
        var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            fill: 'red',
            width: 20,
            height: 20
        });

        // "add" rectangle onto canvas
        canvas.add(rect);   
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

If not working, then your browser doesn't support `<canvas>`.